# List<T> to string[]

Tags: c#

Using C#, I have a List of type Foo, which has a string property Bar.
I'd like to convert this List into a string array using the Bar property.

Is there an easy (LINQ?) way of doing this without having to loop through the collection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 List<Foo> l = GetMyList();
 string[] myStrings = l.Select(i => i.Bar).ToArray();
```

Note that like all linq code this still loops through the collection - you just don't write the loop yourself.

Also note that you should avoid calling .ToArray() until the last possible moment. Are you sure an IEnumerable wouldn't be good enough here?

Comment: Yeah, I'm overriding someone else's class which requires a string[].

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
 string[] bars = myList.Select(x => x.Bar).ToArray();
```